# Building a Phone7 application that operates differently per mobile network operator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a product live on a network operators portal at the moment, it is integrated with the operators SMS/MMS messaging and billing interfaces. I would like to build a version of this application to run on Windows Phone 7 devices.

I'd like the application to run for all users but for users that happen to be on the network operator I've integrated with I'd like to offer them a better experience (direct operator billing and sending through the operators MMSC).

An alternative would be to limit the availability of the app to users with handsets on the operator (like the Android marketplaces that exist for the major cell network operators like Verizon and Sprint).

Is any of this possible on the Zune Marketplace for apps and/or on Phone 7 devices?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking to see if I can find out if the consumers phone is connected to Verizon or to Vodafone Sweden? The sort of informaton provided in the form of MNC and MCC? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this I would suggest liasing with your network operator contacts.

You'll need access to the APIs which they have access to (and the public does not through the 3rd party SDK).

You may also want to ship an app with phones they supply also.

Comment: Hi Mick, happily I'm already integrated with my operators API. Getting a pre-load with the operator is a long slow process.

Comment: That's good news re api access, for support with that they should have direct channels to Microsoft for you to go through on any information not already in their posession. It's not available publicly.